# MongoClient: not connected error while trying to use Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

As part of my course, I'm learning MongoDB and now Mongoose. I've written the code exactly as done in the lesson, but when trying to start it with `node app.js`, I get the following error:

```
node app.js
```

Output:

```
(node:25772) ` **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNotConnectedError: MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation**
    `at Object.getTopology (C:\Users\donal\OneDrive\Desktop\Udemy Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:391:11)
    at Collection.insertOne (C:\Users\donal\OneDrive\Desktop\Udemy Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:150:61)
    at NativeCollection.<computed> [as insertOne] (C:\Users\donal\OneDrive\Desktop\Udemy Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:200:33)
    at NativeCollection.Collection.doQueue (C:\Users\donal\OneDrive\Desktop\Udemy Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\collection.js:135:23)
    at C:\Users\donal\OneDrive\Desktop\Udemy Web Development\FruitsProject\node_modules\mongoose\lib\collection.js:82:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:25772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:25772) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have *mongosh* running in a separate tab in the terminal, and I've tried several searches to look for similar problems. How can I fix it?

Here's my *app.js* code in full:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB");

const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  rating: Number,
  review: String
});

const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

const fruit = new Fruit({
  name: "Apple",
  rating: 7,
  review: "Pretty solid as a fruit"
});

fruit.save();
mongoose.connection.close();


const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {

  const collection = db.collection('fruits');

  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, fruits) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(fruits)
    callback(fruits);

  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongoose.connect` is async, so you're trying to execute the code before a connection is established with the database.

```js
const connectToMongo = async() => {
    await mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/fruitsDB", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
    });
    return mongoose;
};
```

You can now use async/await or .then() to wait till a connection is established

```js
(async function () {
    await connecToMongo();

    const fruitSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        rating: Number,
        review: String
    });

    const Fruit = mongoose.model("Fruit", fruitSchema);

    const fruit = new Fruit({
        name: "Apple",
        rating: 7,
        review: "Pretty solid as a fruit"
    });

    fruit.save();
    mongoose.connection.close();


    const findDocuments = function (db, callback) {

        const collection = db.collection('fruits');

        collection.find({}).toArray(function (err, fruits) {
            assert.equal(err, null);
            console.log("Found the following records");
            console.log(fruits)
            callback(fruits);

        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue and the culprit was calling `mongoose.connection.close();` in the body of your JavaScript code. as [AnanthDev mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525092/mongoclient-not-connected-error-while-trying-to-use-mongoose/69525139#69525139), mongoose is asynchronous and ends up closing the connection before it's able to perform the actions.

The following works because `mongoose.connection.close()` is in a callback function and does not run until after the actions is performed.

```
Fruit.insertMany([kiwi, orange, banana], function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        mongoose.connection.close();
        console.log("Successfully saved all the fruits to fruitsDB");
    }
})
```